# How to let CMake to know the library is in some directory?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a library in c:\cppunit\lib, and a header files in c:\cppunit\include.
I come up with this cmake file to build with the library.

How to let CMake to know the library is in c:/cppunit/lib?

```
PROJECT( cppunitest )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( "c:/cppunit/include" )
??? How to let CMake to know the library is in c:/cppunit/lib
SET( cppunitest_SRC main.cpp testset.cpp complex.cpp  )
LINK_LIBRARIES(cppunit)
ADD_EXECUTABLE( cpptest ${cppunitest_SRC})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES("c:/cppunit/lib")
ADD_EXECUTABLE( cpptest ${cppunitest_SRC})
LINK_LIBRARIES(cpptest cppunit)
```